# Compare datetime inside variable with current datetime

Tags: bash, jq

I have the following line:

```
 for custom_field in $(jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.created' 1.json
); do
      echo $custom_field

done
```

Output:

```
2018-03-06T21:24:41.000+0000
2018-03-06T22:48:47.000+0000
```

How to compare current datetime with each output and if it's older than 3 hours to print "old"?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to convert first and subtract the three hours.

Example below converts to seconds and prints true if condition is met.

`date_in_seconds=$(date -d $custom_field +"%s");
[ ${date_in_seconds} -gt 259200 ] && echo true;`

For non GNU versions of the `date` command you can use the following;

`date_in_seconds=$(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "2016-02-22 20:22:14" '+%s')`

Keep in mind that the `EPOCH` will rollover 1 Jan 2036.

Comment: The `date -d "$custom_field"` construct works well with GNU `date` (so Linux et al) but is not portable to POSIX or BSD-based platforms (like MacOS).

Comment: Correct, however that information was not conveyed in the context of the question

Comment: If it *doesn't* say "I need this for Linux" then portability would be a safe assumption, no?

Comment: There is that word again. While a healthy debate on deciphering text between written text is always a great way to waste time, it is just that and nothing more

Comment: Assumptions are fine but part of the reason Stack Overflow is great is that other people than the OP find these answers and may wish to try them out; so a good answer should at least document its limitations. Shell script is notoriously tricky to make completely portable so indicating whether you *tried* might be enough to judge the quality and applicability of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given input like

```
{ "issues":
 [{"id": 1, "fields": {"created": "2018-03-06T21:24:41.000+0000"}},
  {"id": 2, "fields": {"created": "2018-03-06T22:48:47.000+0000"}},
  {"id": 3, "fields": {"created": "2018-03-09T22:48:47.000+0000"}}]}
```

you can use the built-in date manipulation functions to print the old records with something like

```
jq -r '(now-3600*3) as $when | .issues[] |
  select(.fields.created | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+0000") | mktime < $when) |
[.id, .fields.created, "old"]' 1.json
```

where the last line probably needs tweaking to produce exactly the output you want.

Comment: It would probably be better to compute `now` just once, e.g. by starting with `now as $now |`